# GridView Dynamically 2:3 layout data set

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am using one one layout and include 5 times on other layout. but i want to user Grid View instance of incluide layout. Here I am sharing Screen shot. please help me to make this layout in android [image]

```
This is Flipboard layout. and second one is my layout.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridView` does not support this. One has to use a custom linearlayout and add views to it dynamically by setting the layout parameters.

```
Use the class as layout back bone

     public class CompositeView extends LinearLayout {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;

    public CompositeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setClickable(true);
        imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        textView.setSingleLine(true);
        textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        textView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.strip_bg);

        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // this.setClickable(true);

        this.addView(imageView);
        this.addView(textView);
    }

    public void setText(int resid) {
        textView.setText(resid);
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void setIcon(int resid) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resid));
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }
     }

In activity or fragment

         names = new String[] { "Cloud Bingo", "New Bingo Games", "Politricks",
                "Seam Group", "Regular Cloud Bingo" };

        urls = new String[] { "http://www.cloudbingo.co.uk/",
                "http://www.newbingogames.co.uk/",
                "http://www.politricks.co.in", "http://veenagupta.in/",
                "http://www.regularbingo.co.uk/" };

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            view = new CompositeView(getActivity());
            view.setText(names[i]);
            // view.setOnClickListener(this);
            view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            view.setIcon(images[i]);
            view.setId(i); // id of whole linear view
            view.getTextView().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.getImageView().setId(i); // id of just this imageview
            view.getTextView().setId(i);
       }

   Use following logic for your purpose  

     for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            flag++;

            if (flag % 2 == 0) {
                // number is even

                mainLayout.addView(compositeList.get(i));

            }

            else {
                Log.v("in", "else");
                secondaryLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                params.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 15);

                secondaryLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                secondaryLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                LinearLayout leftLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                leftLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));

                leftLayout.addView(compositeList.get(i));
                secondaryLayout.addView(leftLayout);

                i++;

                if (i < images.length) {
                    LinearLayout rightLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                    LayoutParams rParams = new LayoutParams(0,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

                    rParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

                    rightLayout.setLayoutParams(rParams);

                    rightLayout.addView(compositeList.get(i));

                    secondaryLayout.addView(rightLayout);

                }

                else {

                    LinearLayout rightLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                    LayoutParams rParams = new LayoutParams(0,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

                    rParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

                    rightLayout.setLayoutParams(rParams);

                    secondaryLayout.addView(rightLayout);

                }

                mainLayout.addView(secondaryLayout);

            }

        }


flag is equal to -1 initially , I show one image (with text at bottom) for even rows, two images for odd rows

Here is the layout
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me or suggest me how can I make this